# Como eu posso setar uma foto 'avatar' dinamicamente em windows forms?

Tags: c#

Tenho a seguinte linha de código que irá setar a imagem do cliente na tela caso houver, caso não deixará como nulo. Como posso deixar dinâmico, ou seja, caso o cliente não tenha a foto setará uma imagem `avatar` ?

[image: Avatar][1]]

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objCli.CliFoto) == true){
         byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(objCli.CliFoto.Replace("data:image;base64,", ""));
      using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes)){
         picbImagemCli.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
      }
} else {
   picbImagemCli.Image = null;
}
```

Comment: se trocar o ´picbImagemCli.Image = null;` no seu else para a imagem default não resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou criar uma imagem padrão (default) e armazenar nos seu projeto ou na sua database?
Uma vez criada e armazenada, basta só alimentar a sua **PictureBox** ou o seu **objCli.CliFoto** com a imagem padrão, caso o **objCli.CliFoto= null**.